# Why is the US kill rating so different?

Tags: archery, 3d-archery

In European 3D archery we've (besides a few "uncommon" ratings) two basic rating systems:

[image: Rating EU]

### One kill

The yellow, red and blue area is "the kill":

- First arrow - Kill: 20
- First arrow - Body: 16
- Second arrow - Kill: 14
- Second arrow - Body: 10
- Third arrow - Kill: 8
- Third arrow - Body: 4

### Split kill

The yellow and red area is the center kill. The blue area is the kill.

- First arrow - Centerkill: 20
- First arrow - Kill: 18
- First arrow - Body: 16
- Second arrow - Centerkill: 14
- Second arrow - Kill: 12
- Second arrow- Body: 10
- Third arrow - Centerkill: 8
- Third arrow - Kill: 6
- Third arrow - Body: 4

These ratings follow the concept that you score more points if you hit the lethal point of the target to maintain a "hunt like" environment.

[image: How the kill looks like]

*Split kill: Green Arrow 20, Red Arrow 18, White Arrow 16*

This makes sense imho due to the fact that you hit the heart in the "Centerkill" or the lungs in the "Kill":

[image: Kill]

---

However, I noticed (at least) in the US the 3D rating is by far more complex:

[image: US rating]

I don't get a few things about this system. For example I feel like that you have to explicitly aim for the "non-scoring" point to hit it, what makes it a little bit useless. How did this system evolve and how does it make sense?

Comment: According to [this video](https://youtu.be/_JmMOTx_lmw) the ring marked non-scoring in that illustration is actually scored 14 at least in some systems.

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary rules are just that - arbitrary.  One point of difference is that in 3D archery in the USA, you get exactly one arrow per target -- there's no concept of a "split kill".

The ring you list as "non-scoring" is 14 points in ASA tournaments, but non-scoring in IBO tournaments.  The smaller "upper/lower" 12 are only valid for ASA, and the middle 12 is only valid for IBO.

[image: 3D scoring for various associations]

https://dmtargets.com/scoring/

Why?  Who knows.  But they have to be different or you wouldn't have two associations to join.

In other news, NFAA and USA Archery / World Archery use different rules too -- For instance: NFAA allows "barebow" to have a 12-inch stabilizer, where USA Archery / World Archery requires the whole bow to fit through a 122 mm ring when unstrung.